# ion-nav-bar ng-class not styling

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-class

```
<ion-nav-bar ng-class="{'bar-positive': isAndroid, 'bar-stable': !isAndroid}">
</ion-nav-bar>

<ion-tabs ng-class="{'tabs-positive': isAndroid, 'tabs-icon-top': true}">

  <!-- Account Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Account" icon="ion-ios7-gear" href="#/tab/account">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-account"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

When I use the following markup, only the ion-tabs is styled - not the ion-nav-bar. How can I get them both to be styled, and why isn't the ion-nav-bar getting styled?

Comment: are they sharing same scope/controller? add more html please

Comment: It's a controller-less template with isAndroid bound to the $rootScope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, never mind. [There's an issue for this on github.](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/2732) Also, I've found a somewhat convoluted workaround that should be fine until they fix the ion-nav-bar directive:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="{{ isAndroid ? 'bar-positive' : 'bar-stable' }}">
  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

Comment: @FutureMe Note that this workaround doesn't work nicely with `<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">`.

Answer (score 0):

Above Github issue has been closed now.

Ionic Team Member Mike's codepen work gives us a proper solution, though it *doesn't* seem to be a ***nice*** workaround.

Here's the extract of his snippets:

```
  // We need to be able to add a class the cached nav-bar
  // Which provides the background color
  var cachedNavBar = document.querySelector('.nav-bar-block[nav-bar="cached"]');
  var cachedHeaderBar = cachedNavBar.querySelector('.bar-header');

  // And also the active nav-bar
  // which provides the right class for the title
  var activeNavBar = document.querySelector('.nav-bar-block[nav-bar="active"]');
  var activeHeaderBar = activeNavBar.querySelector('.bar-header');
  var barClass = attrs.navBarClass;
  var ogColors = [];
  var colors = ['positive', 'stable', 'light', 'royal', 'dark', 'assertive', 'calm', 'energized'];
  var cleanUp = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
      var currentColor = activeHeaderBar.classList.contains('bar-' + colors[i]);
      if (currentColor) {
        ogColors.push('bar-' + colors[i]);
      }
      activeHeaderBar.classList.remove('bar-' + colors[i]);
      cachedHeaderBar.classList.remove('bar-' + colors[i]);
    }
  };
```

https://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/dozjvv

In a word, we should manage some DOM operations.